# How can I fix missing nuget references after moving project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I had a project structure like this:

```
 WebApp
-- WebApp
-- WebApp.sln
 WebApp.Tests
-- WebApp.Tests.csproj
```

I moved WebApp.Tests into WebApp using a move (simple click & drag into the WebApp folder). I edited WebApp.sln to fix the project reference so that it will load.

When I build, Nuget complains that packages are missing and to do a restore.
I downloaded and used nuget.exe restore on my solution and it reported everything was there.

Based on other Stack Overflow answers, I have tried the following:

- Edit the test project reference hint paths. I changed from ..\WebApp\packages\PACKAGE to ..\packages\PACKAGE
- Reload Visual Studio (multiple times)
- Delete contents of packages folder and bin/obj folders of the projects
- Use the package manager console to reinstall packages on the Test Project

All of these failed to fix the problem. When I used the package manager to try to reinstall the packages with the command, it gave me the same error that project building does - I must restore the packages first.

Is there any quick way to fix my project? I really don't want to go through each package and uninstall/reinstall manually. Also, how could I have prevented this problem in the first place? Is there a built-in way to move project locations?

Comment: There is likely a check at the bottom of the project file that is looking for the existence of the packages folder or some of its contents.

Comment: Moving projects around usually breaks stuff if there are cross project references or solution items (such as packages) being referenced. That's one of the reasons why Solution Folders (inside the solution explorer) are virtual.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks! There was a check for the existence of a package that had the old relative path. I thought it was just an error report that was embedded in the project file, but once I fixed the Exists(../project), it compiled just fine.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There was XML similar to this at the end of my project file:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\WebApp\packages\SPECIFICPACKAGE')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\WebApp\packages\SPECIFICPACKAGE'))" />
</Target>
```

By changing the ..\Webapp\packages to ..\packages like the rest of the file, my solution compiles just fine now.

Comment: Do you have idea how to restore reference from nuget restore command. I mistakenly delete all my project reference and i don't wanna add it manually.

Comment: Just as future reference - I move my projects into a project folder which causes this problem. `..\packages` needs to be changed to `..\..\packages` and then add the project back into the solution

Comment: Oh My Goodness, I thought I was going insane. Once again, stack overflow to the rescue. Now I know to look at error conditions in the app for these types of ghosts.

Comment: For me, I just deleted the XML you mentioned

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue where I physically moved a project folder into the src folder and got the missing packages error. My fix was to open up the .csproj file in notepad and replace every instance of 
this:

> ..\packages\

with this:

> ..\..\packages\

It solved the issue...